Creating landscape "sheet", two pages per sheet, hyperlinks intact
I have a working document with lots of graphics and everything nicely placed.  It is set up for double-sided printing so that every other page has a slightly wider margin on the inside where the book would be bound.  I would like to create a .pdf (I am using XeLaTeX for compilation) file with two facing pages per sheet, even-numbered pages on the left, odd on the right, just as if you have a book open.  The resulting page size--or sheet size--should be double the width (so in landscape, I am treating width as the longer side) of the original pages.  The height (shorter side in landscape) will remain the same. I do not want a booklet format where the pages are ordered for stapling/binding.  First sheet should have blank on left, page 1 on right.  Second sheet: page 2 on left, 3 on right.  And so forth.
The pdfpages package does a great job of this with very little code.  But it destroys the hyperlinks.
I should mention early on that setting the page up as landscape, two-column with the sizes, margins, and column separator adjusted to compensate does not work--at least not easily.  It misnumbers the pages and, while I think I could find a workaround for that, it also messes with wrap figures and wrap tables.  I am not looking to redesign the whole document.  I think the solution should keep the existing page structure intact and "wrap" it in some larger entity.  It seems like there should be an easy way to do this.
I think the newpax package is the fix, but I cannot discern easily from the documentation how to modify the code to get what I need.  I am not even sure what the examples in the documentation are supposed to do.  It looks like they merge documents and I only have the one.  Before asking this question, I searched high and low on the internet and I have found bits and pieces and related questions, but nothing that hits home (which seems strange: it's hard to believe I am the first with this requirement).
So the question: how to create the document described above and keep hyperlinks intact?

what do you mean "you only have the one"? You have two documents: the original one with the hyperlinks, and the new one which uses pdfpages to load the other one. newpax should work (but I would recommend to use lualatex instead of xelatex for the receiving document, that makes it much easier).  Unrelated: the larger margin in books is on the outside not in the inside. The inner margins are smaller as the two inner margin sums up to one large block, look into a real book and check that.

@Ulrike Fischer Thank you, I’ll try that when I get back and let you know how it goes. Your comment about inside vs. outside would explain a pet peeve of mine. Book publishers need to revisit this practice. Gone are the days when you can open a book flat on a surface. If you try to do that now with these glorified pads (Springer!), you’ll be picking up pages for weeks afterward. As a result, it is very difficult to read the insides of the pages because they’re buried in the “binding” (gluing). CRC Press is particularly bad about this. Too much margin outside, not enough inside.

The binding correction is something different to margins, see the key bindingoffset in the geometry documentation.

@ Ulrike Fischer Okay I tried it and it compiled the document.  I had to install all the available MikTeX updates first. It threw an error the first time and I heeded your advice about having an up-to-date TeX system.  The result looks perfect, but the hyperlinks still don't work.  I'm pretty sure it found them because it changed their color from blue to dark blue (?).  I used hyperref for the original document (although I don't know if that matters).  They do not behave like hyperlinks: the mouse cursor does not change to indicate that it is over a hyperlink.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

@ Ulrike Fischer I should have mentioned that I used LuaTeX to run your file.  It is only dealing with my document through the .pdf version, I presume, but I am not really sure.

no, I have no idea as it works for me. make a small example, compile in an empty folder. Then zip everything (including log-files) and put it somewhere for download.

@Ulrike Fischer I shut TeXStudio down and reopened it and tried it a second time and the result worked.  Perfectly.  The first time I opened from the viewer built into TeXStudio which opened it in the browser and I saved from there.  After reopening TeXStudio, when I ran it again nothing opened in the viewer, so I suspect I was working with the old pdfpages version of my document and when I saved it from the browser, it overwrote what your code had written.  This time I opened the pdf in Sumatra right after running your file and it works perfectly out of the box.  Thanks for all your help!

If you have a document with links you can use newpax with pdfpages like this to preserve the links. This requires lualatex for the receiving documnt, and it also requires a rather current tex system.
\DocumentMetadata{} %required!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpax}
\directlua{require("newpax")}
\directlua
{
 newpax.writenewpax("docwithlink") %adapt to your document
}
\newpaxsetup{usefileattributes=true}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,landscape]{docwithlink}
\end{document}


This helped a lot to understand how newpax works. One question: pdfpages offers the option "addtotoc". I can add an entry to the toc for the included pdf. "addtotoc={1,section,1,{april-paper},april-paper}" will insert an entry at section level into the new document and if I use hyperref, it will produce a bookmark as well. Now, my included document has its own toc. Could the pdfpages packes in theory be improved to include the inserted documents toc under the entry added with addtotoc?

@KeksDose please do not ask complex questions in comments. That pings only me and so basically asks for personal support.
